# How to find errors in cumulative range of mySQL raws?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with cumulative range, where value of summarize column increase constantly. However, there are some errors in a range and some value are incorrect. How could I form a request to find them?

```
-----+-------------+
  id +   value     +
-----+-------------+
  1  +   1 050     +
-----+-------------+
  2  +   1 055     +
-----+-------------+
  3  +   1 075     +
-----+-------------+
  4  +   185       +
-----+-------------+
  5  +   1 094     +
-----+-------------+
  6  +   1 120     +
-----+-------------+
  7  +   175       +
-----+-------------+
  8  +   1 240     +
-----+-------------+
  9  +   1 252     +
-----+-------------+
```

You can see that there are `id=4 and id=7` have such errors.

Comment: What data type is value and what does 1 050 (for example) signify/mean?

Comment: @P.Salmon, value is INT type and this mean, for example, that your ranking is 1050. If you increase it, than you have higher value. It could only rise, not fall.

Comment: Go on. Try something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to find a solution with some cycle. Give you example in php which return you id+1 values:

```
$sum = 0; 
for ($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++) {
   if ($i==0) $sum = $value[$i];
   if ($sum < $value[$i]) 
      echo $i; 
   $sum = $value[$i]; 
}
```